# What are the best practices for format, syntax, and semantics in Java?

Tags: java, syntax, semantics

So I've looked at a few tutorials online, seen quiet a few videos, and read part one of [The Complete Reference Java Seventh Edition](http://memberfiles.freewebs.com/74/74/55387474/documents/Java%20The%20Complete%20Reference,%207th%20Edition.pdf). I have found different syntax and semantics for almost each program so I figured this would be the best place to ask.

What are the best practices for syntax and semantics for coding in Java?
Should { go on the same line, or start a new line?

EX:

```
public void main(String[] args){
//Code
}
```

OR

```
public void main(String[] args)
{
//Code
}
```

Should it be `public void main(String[] args)` or `public void main(String args[])`? I know they do the same thing, but what is considered "best practice"?

Also, what are best practices when it comes to variable names, method names, class names, and package names?

It appears as `final` variables are consistantly CAPITALIZED. But almost all other code I've seen examples of seems to never follow the same format.

I don't assume it makes all the word of difference, but I would like to have clear and concise code for future developers to read code that I develop.

Whitespace seems to be inconsistent when it comes to `for`, `while`, `switch`, `if`, and other statements/loops. Considering best practices, which should get the white space after the keyword and which ones do not?

I would also like to find out about tabs and spaces. Should I just resort to tabbing in? 2 spaces? 4?

Any input would be greatly appreciated. I have looked, and failed, to find a compilation of format, syntax, and semantics.

Comment: format: use eclipse, Java formatting rules and ctrl+shift+f

Comment: There is no right answer, so this question is not best suited to Stack Overflow. One of the other [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/) Q&A sites might be a better fit for this question.

Comment: A lot of this comes down to personal preference, but here's Oracle's [java coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

Comment: If you're completely at a loss, this isn't the worst place to start: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html (the original Sun guidelines).  They're pretty close to the default Eclipse formatting rules.

Answer (score 1):

There are [official code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) but besides that it is really just personal preference. However I recommend using the official conventions so that other people familiar with it (most are) can easily read your code.